# MySQL trigger is not working with PHP application-generated transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have a problem that whenever I start a transaction from the PHP script, the trigger is not raising the intended exception to application. The trigger works fine into DBMS's environment, either being accessed via terminal or PHPMyAdmin.

In my database, I have the following tables and a trigger intended to avoid zero values at qtt column:

```
CREATE TABLE Acquisition (
 id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,

(...)

);

CREATE TABLE AcquisitionItem (
 id int(11) unique NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 acquisition int(11) NOT NULL,
 qtt decimal(12,3) unsigned NOT NULL,

(...)

 CONSTRAINT fkAcquisitionItem FOREIGN KEY (acquisition) REFERENCES  Acquisition (id)
);

delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER chk_zero_qtt BEFORE UPDATE ON AcquisitionItem 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    if new.qtt = 0 then
        begin
            signal sqlstate '45000'
            set message_text = 'Zero at qtt';
        end;
    end if;
end //

delimiter ;
```

In my PHP application, I have the following classes:

```
class ConnectionFactory {
    
    (...)
    private $conn;

    function __construct(){

        try {
          $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->server;dbname=$this->db", $this->user, $this->pass);
    $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $ex) {    
         (...)
        }

    }

    public function getConnection(){
       return $this->conn;
    }
}

class AcquisitionDAO {
(...)

    public function update(Acquisition $acq): ?string {

        try {

            $conn = (new ConnectionFactory())->getConnection();

            $itemDAO = new AcquisitionItemDAO();

            $dbItems = $itemDAO->selectIdsByAcquisition($acq->getId());

            $insertedItems = $this->checkInsertedItems($acq->getItems());
            $updatedItems = $this->checkUpdatedItems($dbItems, $acq->getItems());
            $deletedItems = $this->checkDeletedItems($dbItems, $acq->getItems());

            $conn->beginTransaction();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("update Acquisition set (...) where id = :id");
            (...)
            $stmt->bindValue(':id', $acq->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $stmt->execute();

            if(sizeof($deletedItems) > 0){
                foreach ($deletedItems as $item) {
                    $itemDAO->delete($conn, $item);
                }
            }

            if(sizeof($updatedItems) > 0){
                foreach ($updatedItems as $item) {
                    $itemDAO->update($conn, $acq->getId(), $item);

                }
            }

            if(sizeof($insertedItems) > 0){
                foreach ($insertedItems as $item) {
                    $itemDAO->insert($conn, $acq->getId(), $item);

                }
            }

            $con->commit();

            $stmt->closeCursor();
            $conn = null;
      
            return null;

        }catch(PDOException $ex){

            $conn->rollBack();

            (...)

            return $ex->getMessage();

        }
    }

(...)
}

class AcquisitionItemDAO {
(...)

    public function update(PDO $conn, int $AcqId, AcquisitionItem $item): void {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("update AcquisitionItem set (...) qtt = :qtt where id = :id");

        $stmt->bindValue(':qtt', $item->getQtt(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $item->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->closeCursor();

    }

(...)
}
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.40, PHP 7.2.24 and Apache 2.4.29. The MySQL tables are using InnoDB engine.

I have already tried to:

1. Create the following procedure in order to verify either the problem was from DBMS, so I believe that is not the case. It fires the trigger as expected and prevent first update to be commited;

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN 
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE AcquisitionItem set qtt = 10 where id = 307;
UPDATE AcquisitionItem set qtt = 0 where id = 306;

COMMIT;

END // 

DELIMITER ;
```

2. Switch trigger's create statement from BEFORE to AFTER;
3. Use `CAST(new.qtt AS DECIMAL(12,3)) = 0.000` instead of `new.qtt = 0` into the trigger's if statement, since the PDO::PARAM_STR is being used in the prepared statement;
4. Remove `$stmt->closeCursor()` from AcquisitionItemDAO->update();
5. Set different values to PDO attributes PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT(false), PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES(false) and PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT(true).

None of these worked. Whenever a zero value comes from application, the trigger is completely ignored and the qtt column is updated with a zero value.

I would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Enable General log. Obtain the queries executed by your application, compare them with those executed via "DBMS's environment".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Akina! By doing it I could notice that the MySQL PDO driver transaction is actually performing a DELETE and an INSERT, preserving the keys, instead of an UPDATE. I changed the CREATE TRIGGER statement to BEFORE INSERT and it works.

Comment: @Alexandre I recommend you to store UPDATE trigger nevertheless - maybe in future you'd alter PDO to something... Create separate stored procedure and call it from both triggers - this allows to have one code copy for both triggers.

Comment: Thanks again, @Akina. Appreciate your recommendation and I think it's a very elegant solution. It is indeed a good practice to decouple the validation code into a procedure and call it on both triggers, since I'll need to validate it either way. I'll implement it as you said. I'm also very grateful that you introduced me to a good way of checking the communication between the application and the database.

Comment: Do not forget that INSERT trigger have no OLD pseudotable, do not access it in the SP.